# trailing stop loss implementation in pine script study

Tags: pine-script

I am using a simple trailing stop loss setup in one of my strategies (code as shown below). How can i use the same setup in a study script? any help would be highly appreciated.

```
strategy.exit("long_tsl", "ChBrkLE", trail_points = 4000, trail_offset = 1500)
strategy.exit("short_tsl", "ChBrkSE", trail_points = 4000, trail_offset = 1500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to keep track of if you're long or short, as well as the stop price based on your trailing numbers. Update the stopPrice every candle depending on if you're long or short when price moves in your direction, and also check if your stop was hit every candle, then update your variables accordingly.

I updated this blog post with more details: https://marketscripters.com/pine-script-strategy-vs-study/